# Listen to Wi-Fi (Direct) availability on Android O (API >= 26)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi

Considering the [new broadcast limitations](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#broadcasts) where apps that target Android O can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest I've been wondering what options I have if I'm interested in detecting wifi state changes?

The [list of exceptions](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-broadcasts.html) doesn't help here, the suggestion for apps that previously registered for an implicit broadcast can get similar functionality by using a [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) job doesn't either.

While [JobInfo.Builder.setRequiredNetworkType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetworkType(int)) and [NetworkRequest.Builder.addTransportType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.Builder.html#addTransportType(int)) are pretty close, they both assume the app is interested in a connected network, what for Wi-Fi Direct (P2P) isn't always desirable -- imagine a scenario when the user enables Wi-Fi, that triggers a receiver which checks for nearby devices and offers some action.

Until Android O this was quite easy, one could listen to `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` or `WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` in the manifest but the new rules make this impossible. I guess the idea is that if the user is interested in nearby devices, an app should be used for that purpose. Only workaround I can think of is making `JobScheduler` firing a job every minute or so to check wifi state manually but that is totally against the idea of battery saving which those rules try to enforce.